# What software is available to dim the screen brightness and contrast?

Tags: display, brightness, system-settings, contrast

Is there any software for Ubuntu 22.04 to dim the screen with control over hue, gamma, saturation, brigthness and contrast?

I work in this desktop environment 10 hours a day so I need a low level of light to be comfortable reading the screen.

I want 2% contrast and 2% brighness on my laptop screen.

I can't work with third party software. I can't install any of them because a lot of them don't work with my version of Ubuntu.

If there is a way to do this with a terminal command, that would also be helpful.

ive tried xcalib but it didn't work it give me an error

```
xcalib -b 20% -v
Error - unsupported ramp size 0
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried and what problems you are having so we don't recommend what you've already tried? Maybe we can try to find out why it is that you can't install *any* software, because that sounds unusual... Also, keep in mind that in most cases, software can't dim your screen backlight, which is commonly the cause of the kind of eye strain you are describing. The best solution may be to dim your display backlight using the display's own settings.

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info that belongs in the question. Use edit and add the info to the question. Comments are where we ask you for more info.

Comment: ok thank you.. my graphic hardware is GT218M [GeForce 310M] does nvdia have a software that control contrast and brightness for linux OS?